# Overriding RouteValueDictionary in a Constraint in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just started using ASP.NET Core MVC and I want one route (global slug) to go to multiple controllers and actions depending on what type of page I'm serving to the user. For example, I want to use {*slug} for category and product pages.

I'm trying to override the default controller and action in a constraint.

In past versions of MVC, you could change either values["controller"] or values["action"] in a constraint and it would re-route to the appropriate controller and action.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
                    {
                        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Category",
                            template: "{*slug}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Home" },
                            constraints: new { slug = new PageConstraint() }
                            );
                    });

    }

}


public partial class PageConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public virtual bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var slug = values["slug"] != null ? values["slug"].ToString() : null;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slug))
        {
            // Homepage
            return true;
        }

        // Get category service
        var categoryService = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ICategoryService>();

        var category = categoryService.GetBySlug(slug);

        if (category == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        values["controller"] = "Category";
        values["action"] = "Listing";
        values["category"] = category;

        return true;
    }
}
```

In PageConstraint, I look to see if the Category exists, and if it does, it changes the Controller to Category and the Action to Listing in the RouteValueDictionary. However, when I debug the code through, it still goes to the Controller Page and the Action Home.

Anyone know why this is happening, or whether there is a better way of doing this? I know I could have one action in a controller doing all the work that the constraint is, but I would prefer to house the code in separate controllers and actions.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could try to implement custom `IRouter`

```
public class RouterFromAppSettings : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter _defaulRouter;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public RouterFromAppSettings(IRouter defaulRouter
        , IConfiguration config)
    {
        _defaulRouter = defaulRouter;
        _config = config;
    }
    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        var controller = _config.GetSection("Router").GetValue<string>("Controller");
        var action = _config.GetSection("Router").GetValue<string>("Action");
        context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controller;
        context.RouteData.Values["action"] = action;
        await _defaulRouter.RouteAsync(context);
    }
    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        return _defaulRouter.GetVirtualPath(context);
    }
}
```

And then register it in `Startup.cs` like

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.Routes.Insert(0, new RouterFromAppSettings(routes.DefaultHandler,Configuration));

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```